# get mysql record older than one month only

Tags: mysql, datetime

How to get mysql record older than 30 days? my code will get all the records even which are inserted two months ago .

WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

I want only one month ago not bigger than one month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both start and end date in the filter.

```sql
WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INVERVAL 2 MONTH
  AND date <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

It's verbose and repetitive, but that's an affliction of all SQL code.

Calendar months? If you, on May 7th or anytime in May, want to ask for the calendar month of April, it would be this

```sql
WHERE date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
  AND date <  LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

- `LAST_DAY('2021-05-07')` gets you '2021-05-31',
- `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` then gets you '2021-06-01', then
- `- INTERVAL 2 MONTH` finally gets you '2021-04-01'

It's easy to read and reason about.

`CURDATE()` gives today's date in place of the current date and time given by `NOW()`. Lots of historical reporting doesn't care about time of day, just calendar day. So it might be smart to use `CURDATE()`, depending on your application.